# How to convert "Thu Jun 5 10:59:10 CDT 2014" into python datetime object?

Tags: python, date

How to convert "Thu Jun  5 10:59:10 CDT 2014" into python datetime object?

I can't seem to get it to work due to the CDT. %Z for that is throwing errors :(

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, working example](http://sscce.org) and the full error traceback.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use usual methods from `datetime` to construct the object here. As [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), `strptime` can work only with `(empty), UTC, EST, CST`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Thu Jun 05 10:59:10 UTC 2014", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 5, 10, 59, 10)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Thu Jun 05 10:59:10 CDT 2014", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Thu Jun 05 10:59:10 CDT 2014' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

You need to [take a look at `python-dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil), which will parse the object into a *naive* datetime object (it does not take into account the timezone...):

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("Thu Jun 5 10:59:10 CDT 2014")
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 5, 10, 59, 10)
```

Comment: +1 for explaining his actual issue rather than just providing some sort of workaround ... :P

Comment: I thought the timezone values listed in the doc were just examples, not an exhaustive list. I find `strptime` with a format string similar to yours (I used `%X` instead of `%H:%M:%S`) works fine with CDT (which is my timezone) and UTC (although no time conversion is performed) but fails with other timezones.

Comment: @FredLarson `%X` is a shortcut for `%H:%M:%S`. Are you sure for CDT? Aren't you using `pytz`?

Comment: I did `datetime.strptime(ds, '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y')`. Don't know anything about `pytz`. CDT, CST, UTC and GMT are all accepted. I've also tried EDT, EST, PDT, and PST. Those fail for me with the same exception you showed.

Answer (score 0):

`dateutil` can parse most date formats without effort

`$ easy_install dateutil`

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("Thu Jun 5 10:59:10 CDT 2014")
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 5, 10, 59, 10)
```

(I dont think it handles the timezone quite right though... but it certainly parses it... )