# Python datetime does not match format

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I went through datetime python page, and other related pages, but unable to get this thing to work.

I have the following string that I want to convert to python date object.

May 29, 2018 10:40:06 CDT AM:

I use the following to match, but python2.7 is giving me doesnt match error.

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(line, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %Z %p:')
```

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064906/how-to-convert-thu-jun-5-105910-cdt-2014-into-python-datetime-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though `CDT` is not a valid timezone name as it works with `GMT`.

```
>>> str(datetime.strptime('May 29, 2018 10:40:06 GMT AM:', '%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %Z %p:'))
'2018-05-29 10:40:06'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil import parser
print (parser.parse("May 29 13:40:06  CDT 2018"))
```

Output

```
2018-05-29 13:40:06
```

Reference: [python-dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil)